# Sum using CASE when using Len(column_name)

Tags: sql

I am writing a query that counts the number of records for which the character count is less than 11.

```
SELECT sum(CASE when LEN(Summary) > 11 then 0 else 1) AS [SummaryErrorCnt],
       sum(CASE when LEN(ResolutionNotes) >11 then 0 else 1) AS [ResolutionNotesErrorCnt]
FROM dbo.TicketLog
```

But I get the error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

I am closing the parenthesis correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Every `CASE` needs an `END`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `END` keyword fro the `CASE` expressions, eg:

```
CASE when LEN(Summary) > 11 then 0 else 1 END
                                          ^^^-- must close CASE with END
```